# A basic doubt on definite intergal involving infinity

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is the following statement valid ?

$$ [x]^\infty_0 = \int^{\infty}_{0}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the statement is true.

---

Long answer.

Regarding the formula $\displaystyle  [x]^\infty_0 = \int \limits^{\infty}_{0}\mathrm dx$,

- the LHS is short for $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}(x-0)$, **if** the limit exists (finitely), and it is meaningless otherwise. In case it doesn't exist, the formula $\displaystyle  [x]^\infty_0 = \int \limits^{\infty}_{0}\mathrm dx$ isn't a statement at all, it's a string of symbols.
- the RHS is short for $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \left(\int \limits_0^x \mathrm dt\right)$, **if** this limit exists. If it does, $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \left(\int \limits_0^x \mathrm dt\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \left([t]_0^x\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \left(x-0\right)$.

Thus the formula $\displaystyle  [x]^\infty_0 = \int \limits^{\infty}_{0}\mathrm dx$ is a true statemenet whenever any of the limits exists and it isn't a statement at all if one of the limits doesn't exist.

---

What's below is an answer to the first version of the question and, for that reason, hidden in a spoiler.

> The formula $\displaystyle  [x]^\infty_0 = \int \limits^{1}_{0}\mathrm dx$ isn't even a statement. The RHS is simply $1$, but the LHS is short for $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}\left(x-0\right)$ which, in this context, doesn't exist as it isn't a real number, so you can't really claim that the 'equality' is a statement.
> If you are to consider $+\infty$ as a proper entity, then it is a statement, but it is false because $+\infty \neq 1$.

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrongly. It is not 1. it is infinity in the right side.

Comment: @prasenjit Give me a few minutes. I've been trying to post an answer, but I keep losing my work due to Chrome crashing.